# Achieve some TradingView Chart like functions with amStockCharts v3

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, amstock

I am using amStockCharts for my website and want to add some tradingView chart-like functionality in my charts for users. I know that Trading view Chart is a full featured chart and not all the functionality can be met with amStockCharts, but I am ready write code myself to do this.

Basically, below are the 3 main things I wish to achieve as shown in the image described with red text and yellow background:

[image]

**My question is whether this is achievable with amStockCharts? If yes, please guide me in the right direction.**

Comment: [Candlesticks](https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v3/multiple-panels-v3/) are the only thing supported in your list of things you marked off.

Comment: Right, But my question is whether it is possible to add the above features myself?

Comment: Not unless you have the unminified source code to hack that in yourself. There aren't any workarounds you can implement to get those features through the API alone.

Comment: In that case, can I get the unminified source code? :) I am wondering why these basic features are not included in amStockCharts... May be I can contribute to enhance it...

Comment: Uh, do you have an OEM license? :) If so, you can do whatever you want with it. AmCharts 3 is not open source and is being sunsetted in favor of v4, so we're definitely not adding anything to v3 unless we have to address a major bug. v4's stock charts are being worked on...ETA is sometime this year but I don't have a definite date. v4 does come with source (linkware license), so you'll probably want to wait until v4 stock chart drops and fiddle with that to suit your needs.

Comment: Looking at this again, you can probably do the pitch line with multiple graphs and `fillToGraph` but it won't be an exact match (see the [fill between graphs example](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/using-fills-between-two-graphs-on-stock-chart/)). You have to provide the data for those lines. [Trend lines](https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v3/trend-lines-v3/) might also be an option, but they lack any fill properties. Position is probably a guide line but lacks the label colors and fill. While it can't generate the exact same output, perhaps it's close enough for you w/o the source.